# Javascript menu hover event not working on JQuery loaded html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a site that was built a few years ago, it was constructed using nested tables which is turning out to be a major issue when trying to convert the template into a responsive design.
It is an html site with a lot of SEO so the client is not willing to convert to php and risk loosing the links.
So, I decided to use the jquery load method to load the menu into a div, so if I need to add a page or change the current menu, I only have to change 1 page.

So the menu uses an older javascript code to hide the dropdowns:

```
var menu=function(){
var t=15,z=50,s=6,a;
function dd(n){this.n=n; this.h=[]; this.c=[]}
dd.prototype.init=function(p,c){
    a=c; var w=document.getElementById(p), s=w.getElementsByTagName('ul'), l=s.length, i=0;
    for(i;i<l;i++){
        var h=s[i].parentNode; this.h[i]=h; this.c[i]=s[i];
        h.onmouseover=new Function(this.n+'.st('+i+',true)');
        h.onmouseout=new Function(this.n+'.st('+i+')');
    }
}
dd.prototype.st=function(x,f){
    var c=this.c[x], h=this.h[x], p=h.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
    clearInterval(c.t); c.style.overflow='hidden';
    if(f){
        p.className+=' '+a;
        if(!c.mh){c.style.display='block'; c.style.height=''; c.mh=c.offsetHeight; c.style.height=0}
        if(c.mh==c.offsetHeight){c.style.overflow='visible'}
        else{c.style.zIndex=z; z++; c.t=setInterval(function(){sl(c,1)},t)}
    }else{p.className=p.className.replace(a,''); c.t=setInterval(function(){sl(c,-1)},t)}
}
function sl(c,f){
    var h=c.offsetHeight;
    if((h<=0&&f!=1)||(h>=c.mh&&f==1)){
        if(f==1){c.style.filter=''; c.style.opacity=1; c.style.overflow='visible'}
        clearInterval(c.t); return
    }
    var d=(f==1)?Math.ceil((c.mh-h)/s):Math.ceil(h/s), o=h/c.mh;
    c.style.opacity=o; c.style.filter='alpha(opacity='+(o*100)+')';
    c.style.height=h+(d*f)+'px'
}
return{dd:dd}
}();
```

I didn't really think it would cause an issue as the css is working fine and I don't see any errors, here is how I include that html page.

```
<script> 
$(function(){
  $("#menud").load("menu.html"); 
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

however the dropdowns are not displaying on hover, I looked at the page in the inspector and see a lot of properties on the ul on the original page, but when inspecting the ul on the new page, it has no properties, and nothing happens when I hover over a link.
here is the link to the test page: http://pezzelectric.com/about-mobile.html

Instead of me posting 2 links, you can just remove the "/about-mobile.html" and go to the home page or any other page to see how the menu is supposed to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood correctly, I think you may be missing an initialisation script in your new page (/about-mobile.html).

The home page has the following near the bottom of the page:

```
<script type=text/javascript>
    var menu=new menu.dd("menu");
    menu.init("menu","menuhover");
</script>
```

and your new page doesn't. I tested it in my console on `/about-mobile.html` and it seemed to work, but I'm unsure if you couldn't use that for some reason.

Comment: I cant believe i missed that, thank you very much! Sometimes it takes that second pair of eyes to see the obvious.

Comment: @JLongBeard - No problem, I completely agree...I do it all the time!